# Find the numbers

Tags: integers

The sum of two positive integers is $200$. If one is divided by $5$ and the other is divided by $9$, the remainder is $1$ each case. Find the numbers

I have $u+v=200$.
But I can't get the second equation.

Comment: If 5 divides $u$ then you can notice that you can write $u = 5\cdot k +1$. for some constant $k$

Comment: Then there will be two integers K and l

Comment: Then there will be two integers K and m. How would I find their value?

Comment: plug them back into the equation and for different values you'll get different numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One must be of the form $5r+1$ and the other of the form $9s+1$.  Thus you wish to solve $5r+1+9s+1=200$ or $5r+9s=198$.  The solution is not unique unless you add more constraints.  For example the numbers $181$ and $19$ add to $200$ and have the property that you can divide $181$ by $5$ and $19$ by $9$ and get remainders of $1.$  The numbers $126$ and $64$ also have this property.

Answer (score 2):

Given the conditions on $u$ and $v$, we can find $m$ and $n$ such that
\begin{align*}
u &= 5m + 1 \\
v &= 9n + 1.
\end{align*}
Substituting in, we get
$$5m + 9n  = 198$$
From here, we get a few answers. For example, $n = 2$ and $m = 36$, yielding $u = 181$ and $v = 19$. See if you can find some others.

Comment: It gets even easier if you make this $10m = 396-18n$, so you need a multiple of $18$ which ends in $6$, with $n=2$ jumping out as the simplest example.  You do not have  to look at cases larger than $n=\frac{396}{18}$